# How to check if all of multiple values met one or another condition

Tags: kotlin

I would like to check, if all of my variables are either null/other condition or not null/other condition. If some are null and some are not, I would like to return those variables which are null. For example:

```
val value1 = null
val value2 = null
val value3 = null
val value4 = "Toast"

if(value1 != null && value2 != null && value3 != null && value4 != null) return true 
else if (????) return value that are null
```

Maybe I am just brain afk and the solution is easier than I think it is.

Comment: Why don't you just use filter/map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jam the values into a list and filter them?

```
val mylist = mapOf(value1, value2, value3, value4)
val notnulls = mylist.filter{it != null}
```

Now `notnulls` will have the values that aren't null.

I'm pretty sure there's an any{...} as well in there, same as counting whether there's anything left after your filter.

Comment: There is one problem with this approach. All the values are actually Mutablelivedatas. Would that still work?

Comment: Are you mutating them while performing the check?

Comment: No, there are not mutated WHILE performing. But the MutableLiveData.value can be changed of course

Comment: Could you take a snapshot and work on that?

Comment: I don't know how to exactly do that. There is a map function which is triggered everytime the value is changed. But there might be a race condition between the value being checked and the livedata being read

Comment: If there's an observing function surely the thing to do is use that to update a map of flags?

Comment: Is there a function which checks, if All the values in my list are either null or not null?

Comment: Yeah you can use collection.any { it != null}  or collection.all {...}